# Updating <h1> tag with python output using ajax on GAE

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

I've been fiddling around with this for a while now, and been looking around online. I'm new to javascript, jquery and AJAX. How do I call this python script properly so I get the return output from the function instead of the raw code?

I am using google app engine to host a simple name generator type app. I am therefore developing this on my machine locally(with the app on localhost). I have a button that would return the output of my 'generate_name' function and inject it into the html of the page via the jinja2 template engine. So I was using `{{name}}` which was replaced by the output from my python function every time I press the button.

The problem was, while this worked fine on my machine, once It was up on app engine, it was obvious that the entire page was reloading to update the newly generated name, each time the button was pressed. It didn't look good and the images etc. on the page were reloaded every time. I decided to try and use AJAX to just update the `'<h1>'` tag that contains the name.

I put my name generating function and the word lists it uses, into it's own .py file and wrote the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"static/words.py",
            success:function(msg){
                $('h1').html(msg);
            }
        });         
    }); 
});
```

When I press the button now, it just returns the actual code in the python script itself, instead of the return value like I wanted. Here is the python script:

```
#Two large word lists are here

def generate_band_name():
    noun = choice(nouns).strip()
    adj = choice(adjectives).strip()
    return '%s %s' % (adj, noun)

generate_band_name()
```

**and here is the html for the page:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/main.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/main.js"></script>
        <title>Band name generator</title>
    </head>    
    <body>    
        <div class="main">  
            <img src="static/Graffiti.png"/><br>
            <h1></h1><br>
            <button>GENERATE</button>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**and here is my app.yaml file:**

```
application: name-generator
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico


- url: .*/static
  static_dir: static

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

**the directory structure is like this:**

```
C:/code/GAE/name-generator/
C:/code/GAE/name-generator/scripts
C:/code/GAE/name-generator/static
C:/code/GAE/name-generator/templates
```

**EDIT:**

**I have added this to my main.app:**

```
class Generate(MainHandler):

    def generate_band_name(self):
        noun = choice(nouns).strip()     # choice imported from random
        adj = choice(adjectives).strip() # nouns and adjectives are imported lists
        return '%s %s' % (adj, noun)

    def get(self):
        name = self.generate_band_name()
        # I am unsure how to get the ajax script to access
        # the output of generate_band_name

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/generate', Generate)
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok previous answer wasn't right. Trying again. It's all about the yaml:

```
- url: .*/static
  static_dir: static
```

is causing those contents to be returned to the user as-is, such as html, image, javascript, etc.

---

Similar to how you have this elsewhere:

```
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

You'll want to **put this in your yaml for ajax scripts**

```
- url: /ajax/words.py
  script: /ajax/words.py
```

*Edited*. There's got to be a way to map the whole directory, but I don't know it...

And update the javascript to look at `/ajax/words.py`. Technically you could do this with the py in your main folder, but this is cleaner.

Comment: so I should try making a folder 'ajax' and put the script there?

Comment: Looking the the chrome dev tools, I am getting an error: http://localhost:18082/ajax/words.py 404 (Not Found) The word.py file is in the ajax folder(within the directory I mentioned at the end of my post) and the app.yaml file is updated..

Comment: Is it even possible to do this with files on my own computer? I tried changing $.ajax url property to the full file path of the python script and got this error in chrome dev tools: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/code/GAE/name-generator/ajax/words.py. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Comment: It's possible, but I'm doing something wrong. My new edit should work, but you'll have to search for a general directory-wide solution

Comment: This is a completely mistaken answer. See mine for details.

Answer (score 0):

You should treat the server-side path of an Ajax script exactly the same as you would any other handler. That is, since you're using webapp2, it needs to be an actual request handler, accepting a request and returning a response, and mapped as a script URL in the same way as the other handlers. So you wouldn't access /foo/bar.py - you would map /foo/bar either in app.yaml or (more likely) in the routes within main.py, and set it to execute that handler.

**Edit**

I don't understand your example, I'm afraid. But you do seem to be overcomplicating things. Here's how I would do it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.click('#my_button').function() {
      $.get('/my_ajax_url', function(data) {
          $('#dynamic_content').append(data);
      });
  });

<div id="dynamic_content"></div>
<button id="my_button">click me</button>
```

main.py:

```
class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ... load template ...
        self.response.write(my_template.render())

class AjaxHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        return json.dumps(generate_band_names())

app = webapp2.WSGI.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/my_ajax_url', AjaxHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: I was following this route after some digging online. I am now wondering how I might map the url for the new handler.. For example, I have my main.app, which simply renders the page to begin with. In order to start generating names, the button must be pressed(a new name generated per press etc.) Could I then write a new handler in main.app that runs my script each time the button is pressed.. or do I need to write a new handler in a new .py(.app) file?(this is what I have done, but can't figure out how to work it. In either case, what url could I map to the handler that calls the script?

Comment: Surely the url I map to for this new handler would have to be the same url as the main handler in main.app that loads the page initially. The whole point of the ajax script is to not reload the whole page(so presumably a redirect is out of the question), so how do I then properly call a python script, via ajax, from my new handler, so it just updates the <h1> tag?

Comment: Yes, you would write a handler that runs the script. But why would it be the same URL? It can be any URL you want, but it can't be the same as the one that renders the page, because that's already calling the render page handler!

Comment: I would have thought that using a new url(not the initially rendered one) would cause the page to fully reload, at least the first time it's visited. Which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I can't think why you think that. The whole point of ajax is that the JavaScript loads an arbitrary url without changing or refreshing the current page.